# Armature twitches out of position for single frame during animation render

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine

I am running Blender 2.82 and rendering with Eevee.

I have a rigged character performing a simple swiping animation with it's arm. The animation plays correctly in the viewport and renders correctly if I render a single frame. However, if I render an animation, the arm will occasionally twitch out of position for a single frame and then snap back to where it's meant to be throughout the animation. If I go back in and manually render the single frames where the arm twitches out of place it will be positioned correctly.

In this manner I'm able to repair the animation, but manually re-rendering a dozen frames over the course of a 9 second animation gets tedious if I have to go back and make changes.

I previously had a similar issue where I was animating render visibility on objects and they would pop back in and out for single frames when I rendered animation, but would remain invisible if I rendered single frames.

Any insight into what might be happening would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Edgel3D I was unfamiliar with this solution but it worked like a charm! If you want to add it as an answer to the question I'll happily mark it as correct.

Comment: Have copied it as an answer thanks @Skelex  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak for vers's 2.8+ but this is a common occurance and the solution has often turned out to be as simple as saving the Blend file, exiting Blender, deleting any cache folder(s) found in both the project folder and Blender's 'Temporary' folder (as designated in pref's), then reloading the project again. Hope this helps in your case... It may also be that the armature is working against some other modifier or constraint